# how to show a div only for 3 seconds and disappear again using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have my html like this

```
<p id="msgfail"  hidden="hidden" >Theres an error processing ur request</p>
<p id="sucessmsg"  hidden="hidden">Success fully update database</p>
```

when i click a button it triggers attempt to enter data to mysql database. and the corresponding p item is made visible. now my question is how do i make it dissapear again after a timeout ?

i tried it this way

```
if ($("#msgfail").is(":visible")) {
  setTimeout(function() {$("#msgfail").hide();}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: & sorry the id's were mistyped .. p id should be msgfail

Comment: What's wrong with that code? I don't seem to get that "*again*"

Comment: The code you've posted seems to be working – the question is, when does it get executed. Is it inside some event handler?

Comment: I don't know if the hidden attribute is the best way to do this due to the lack of IE support. http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_global_hidden.asp

Comment: it shows on ajax success like  if(data.status) { $("#msgSuccess").show();

Comment: Odd side-note: `#msgfail` and `#successmsg` is pretty inconsistent - either use `#___msg` or `#msg___` and stick with it, it'll pay off in the future

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is something like this what you're thinking?

```
$("#msgfail").delay(3000).hide(1);
```

[Docs for `delay`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/).

Comment: `delay` works with `show()` and `hide()` only when you set a duration.

Comment: Ah, that's what it is. Strange. Thanks! [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U8nTY/), jinni.

Comment: nice @JasonSperske ! liked ur demo

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `setTimeout` which is native to JavaScript.

```
$('#msgfail').show();
setTimeout(function() { $('#msgfail').hide(); }, 3000);
```